# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cacerts

I have ubuntu server that sends request to a website. When I send request it gives

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1131)

error.

I added that website's CA certificate to my trusted certs lists.  Now, I can send request with curl but not with python.

In python, I tried `verify='location/cert.pem'`  and `cert='location/cert.crt'` , but I still get error above.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: did you restart your pc?

Comment: it is ubuntu server.

Comment: in that case, is the certificate self signed?

Comment: looks like your key file is not validating your certificate. So there is chance your key file is not proper.